# Java.util.date - printing its object not value

Tags: java, javascript, struts2, momentjs

Hello i am using struts2 but my textfield is getting Object from Java.util.date instead of its value

Javascript

```
start = moment(start).format();
alert(start);
2014-10-31T00:00:00+00:00
```

but when i try to use value of start in java object , it prints following object

```
java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1416382200000,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Asia/Ulaanbaatar",offset=28800000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=48,lastRule=null],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2014,MONTH=10,WEEK_OF_YEAR=47,WEEK_OF_MONTH=4,DAY_OF_MONTH=19,DAY_OF_YEAR=323,DAY_OF_WEEK=4,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=3,AM_PM=1,HOUR=3,HOUR_OF_DAY=15,MINUTE=30,SECOND=0,MILLISECOND=0,ZONE_OFFSET=28800000,DST_OFFSET=0]
```

how can i get **2014-10-31T00:00:00+00:00** in java (struts2 ) object

Struts2 Getter and Setter

```
@Column(name="EVENT_START") 
    public Calendar getOrder_employee_start() { 
        return order_employee_start;
    }
    public void setOrder_employee_start(Calendar order_employee_start) {
        order_employee_start.getTime();
        this.order_employee_start = order_employee_start;
    }
```

Comment: Can you try using a [`Date`](https://struts.apache.org/release/2.0.x/docs/date.html)? Your title says `java.util.Date` but your code is using `java.util.Calendar`.

Comment: Yes i tried to use Date but Date doesnt get any time , it takes only date

Comment: Show me that code. Because `java.util.Date` most certainly includes time. It is in fact a number of microseconds since [*"the epoch", namely January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT.*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) Per my first link, the fall-back format in struts 2 is [*`DateFormat.MEDIUM`*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#MEDIUM) which is only the date.

Comment: Using Java.Date with getTime(); gives me 1416541128000

Comment: That's the number of milliseconds. `Calendar.getTime()` returns `Date` anyway.

Comment: and struts2 setter makes it to 2014-11-19T00:00:00+00:00 still no time

Comment: I am using following format now in javascript YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm    and it prints 2014/11/21 08:00:00 , but java is not getting time java is printing 2014/11/21 00:00:00

Comment: Create a type converter for the `Date`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `<s:date>` tag to receive the date value on your jsp?

If not you should either return a String value which you could use directly in your textboxes.

Comment: I am using following format now in javascript YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm and it prints 2014/11/21 08:00:00 , but java is not getting time java is printing 2014/11/21 00:00:00

Comment: try using the default <s:date> without any format. Check out this link http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-date-tag-example/

Answer (score 0):

`SimpleDateFormat` can be used to get the desired result.

For instance-

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

SimpleDateFormat sdFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");
```

Then call `sdFormat.format(cal.getTime())`

So, in your case you can do something like `sdFormat.format(order_employee_start.getTime())`